# Change font size for ggplot2 figures (axes titles, labels and numbers)

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I've been struggling to increase the size of my axes labels and titles for ggplot2 function, and really need help on this to increase readability of my figures please.

I've tried several suggestions here, mainly using `theme()` parameters (see example dataframe below) and base_size argument.

```
example.bp <- ggplot(data = a, aes(x = b, y = c, fill = b)) +
  stat_boxplot(aes(b,c),
               geom='errorbar', linetype=1, width=0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.3) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", size = 1) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  xlab("B") +
  ylab("C") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.5), colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, angle = 0),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5),
        panel.background = element_blank())

example.bp

example.bp + annotate(geom = "text", x=1, y=140, label = "n = 8", color = "black") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x=2, y=140, label = "n = 14", color = "black") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x=3, y=140, label = "n = 7", color = "black") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x=4, y=140, label = "n = 15", color = "black")
example.bp + geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

When I try these changes, there aren't error messages, but no changes reflect on the figures.

What are your best suggestions for changing font size of all labels and axes for ggplot2, and integrating this into existing code for the figures?

Comment: Welcome to SO, brandy_odendaal! You mentioned a sample frame, did you forget to add it? Also, it would help to see a complete `ggplot(..) + ...` expression, not just the theme, to see what else might be impacting the inability to control font size. (In general, `element_text(size=.)` should do it, so I'm curious why it's not working for you.)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans! Here is the ggplot expression:

Comment: I don't have your data, but when I compare `gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()` with `gg + theme(axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.5), colour = "black"), axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 24, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, angle = 0), axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 24, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5))`, the labels are clearly different for me (I exaggerated to `size=24` for my own demo).

Comment: I cannot reproduce without seeing your data, are you able to provide a sample of it? I assume you're replaced real variables with `a`, `b`, and `c`; if you have concerns over privacy or proprietary data, that's fine, you should be able to produce fake data that is roughly representative of your real data. Please share what you can using `dput(head(x,20))` or `data.frame(..)` or `read.table(text='...'))`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for demos on using those options. Thank you!

Comment: You can [create](https://emanuelaf.github.io/own-ggplot-theme.html) [custom](https://rpubs.com/mclaire19/ggplot2-custom-themes) a [theme](https://cmdlinetips.com/2022/05/how-to-write-a-simple-custom-ggplot-theme-from-scratch/)

Comment: A helpful post relating to how theme settings interact with your graphic device settings: https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/

Comment: Thanks all for your helpful suggestions! I played around a bit but actually got my original code using theme to work - I needed to add axis.title though for the x- and y-axis titles, too. I was then left with the issue of overlapping labels, but this was an easy fix with label_wrap()